# Can Datalogics Adobe pdf library fix badly formed PDF?

Tags: adobe-pdf-library

I am looking at Datalogic's Adobe pdf library to repair and optimize PDF files for printing. The APDFL v15.0.0PlusP1a (5/18/2016) version release notes make reference to PDFProcessor for C++ but that seems to be missing from the sample files.  The PDFOptimizer looks promising but it does not repair known badly formed PDF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adobe PDF library PDDocOpenwithParams() method allows you to set a flag     *doRepair:*

**doRepair:** *If true, attempt to repair the file if it is damaged; if false, do not attempt to repair the file if it is damaged.*

Will it fix a badly formed PDF? how bad is bad? If Acrobat is able to resolve the issues and display the document then Adobe PDF library should be able to deal with the document also.

Regarding the PDFProcessor sample, in Release v15.0.4PlusP2b the samples were restructured.  The samples listed on our website reflects those changes. Some of the old samples were removed or rewritten.  PDFProcessor has been temporarily removed but available if needed for evaluations or customers use.  The PDFProcessor sample- shows how to convert PDF documents to PDF/A and PDF/X compliant PDF files.

Comment: Who do I contact to get the evaluation version of PDFProcessor?

Comment: PDFProcessor is an Adobe PDF Library sample.  You can request an evaluation of the Adobe PDF Library at: http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdflibrary/eval/  once you have the evaluation you can ask support for a copy of the PDFProcessor sample.